# Adding metaboxes to attachment pages

Tags: metabox, attachments

My script cannot save the value of the dropdown box. I could not find any helpful documentation on this topic, so I have decided to ask the StackExchange community about it.

```
function _cc_add_our_attachment_meta() {
   add_meta_box( 'cc-license-attachment-meta-box', 'License of the Attachment', '_cc_our_attachment_meta_box_callback', 'attachment', 'normal', 'low');
}
add_action( 'admin_init', '_cc_add_our_attachment_meta' );

function _cc_our_attachment_meta_box_callback() {
     global $post; 
     $value = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_license', false);
     if($value == '')
     {
     $value = '0';
     }
?>
<p>Choose a license for this file</p>
<select name="license_id">
<option value="0" <?php selected( '0', $value ); ?>>License 1</option>
<option value="1" <?php selected( '1', $value ); ?>>License 2</option>
<option value="2" <?php selected( '2', $value ); ?>>License 3</option>
<option value="3" <?php selected( '3', $value ); ?>>License 4</option>
<option value="4" <?php selected( '4', $value ); ?>>License 5</option>
<option value="5" <?php selected( '5', $value ); ?>>License 6</option>
</select>
<?php
}

function _cc_attachment_save_our_attachment_meta($post_ID) {
    if( isset( $_POST['license_id'] ) ) {
        $license = $_POST['license_id'];
        switch($license)
        {
            case 0: $license = '0';
            case 1: $license = '1';
            case 2: $license = '2';
            case 3: $license = '3';
            case 4: $license = '4';
            case 5: $license = '5';
            default: $license = '0';
        }
        update_post_meta( $post_ID, '_license', $license );
    }
}

add_action('edit_attachment', '_cc_attachment_save_our_attachment_meta', 10, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

`get_post_meta` returns an array when you set the 3rd parameter to `false`, so `$value` is an array in your metabox callback and you're treating it as string. I assume an attachment has a single value for license, so you want to set that to `true` instead.

Comment: thank you! you are right. on the other hand I have tried to solve this problem (the post meta does not get saved with the "edit_attachment" hook), so my problem is still alive :/

Answer (score 0):

```
function _cc_attachment_save_our_attachment_meta($post_ID) {
    if( isset( $_POST['license_id'] ) ) {
        $license = $_POST['license_id'];
        switch($license)
        {
            case 0: $license = '0'; break 1;
            case 1: $license = '1'; break 1;
            case 2: $license = '2'; break 1;
            case 3: $license = '3'; break 1;
            case 4: $license = '4'; break 1;
            case 5: $license = '5'; break 1;
            default: $license = '0'; break 1;
        }
        update_post_meta( $post_ID, '_license', $license );
    }
}

add_action('edit_attachment', '_cc_attachment_save_our_attachment_meta', 10, 1);
```

Adding some breaks will solve the issue.